# Using VBA in excel - Pad the resulting output of a formula with a 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a block of code using VBA in excel that counts the number of records produced in a file exported from another platform on the very last line of the file.

This file has to contain a specific number of characters to validate. If the record count is 9 or less then it will operate just fine. However, if the record count is 10 or above the character limit is exceeded and it will fail.

Is there a way to embed a line code into the module that will pad the output from this last line of syntax with a leading 0 if the record count is less than 10? If so, I can then alter the earlier part of the code to remove a static character and meet the files requirements regardless of if the record count is above or below 9.

Code is below...The bolded area on the last line of the code at the very end (" & lastrow - 2 & ") is where I need to pad the 0 of the resulting formula.

```
Sub Hidden_macro1()

On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Testing_Report_Out").Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


On Error GoTo 0

Sheets.Add.Name = "Testing_Report_Out"

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrowfooter As Long
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer

Sheets("Testing Report").Select

lastrow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

Sheets("Testing_Report_Out").Select

Range("A1").Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!A4,""   "",'Testing Report'!B4,'Testing Report'!C4,""           "",'Testing Report'!D4,'Testing Report'!E4,"" "",'Testing Report'!F4)"

I = 4
J = 2

Do Until I = lastrow

'Fill 1st formula (:20:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!G" & I & ",'Testing Report'!H" & I & ")"

J = J + 1

'Fill 2nd formula (:23B:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!I" & I & ",'Testing Report'!J" & I & ")"

J = J + 1

'Fill 3rd formula (:32A:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!K" & I & ",'Testing Report'!L" & I & ",'Testing Report'!M" & I & ",'Testing Report'!N" & I & ",'Testing Report'!O" & I & ")"

J = J + 1

'Fill 4th formula (:50K:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!P" & I & ",'Testing Report'!Q" & I & ")"

J = J + 1

'Fill 5th formula (:50K: Addy)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "='Testing Report'!R" & I & ""

J = J + 1

'Fill 6th formula (:57A:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!S" & I & ",'Testing Report'!T" & I & ")"

J = J + 1

'Fill 7th formula (:59:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!U" & I & ",'Testing Report'!V" & I & ")"

J = J + 1

'Fill 8th formula (:59:/ 3)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "='Testing Report'!W" & I & ""

J = J + 1

'Fill 9th formula (:59:/ 5)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "='Testing Report'!X" & I & ""

J = J + 1

'Fill 10th formula (:70:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!Z" & I & ",'Testing Report'!AA" & I & ")"

J = J + 1

'Fill 11th formula (:71A:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "='Testing Report'!AB" & I & ""

J = J + 1

'Fill 12th formula (:72:)

Range("A" & J).Formula = "='Testing Report'!AC" & I & ""


I = I + 1
J = J + 1

Loop

lastrowfooter = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Range("A" & lastrowfooter + 1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!AD4,'Testing Report'!AE4,'Testing Report'!AF4,'Testing Report'!AG4,""           "",'Testing Report'!AH4,'Testing Report'!AI4,'Testing Report'!AJ4," **& lastrow - 2 &** ")"


End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to include the code you are using in your question. It makes things much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Probably using `Format$` but some sample data and the expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Format()` as suggested by @BigBen

```vb
Range("A" & lastrowfooter + 1).Formula = _
   "=CONCATENATE('Testing Report'!AD4,'Testing Report'!AE4,'Testing Report'!AF4," & _
     "'Testing Report'!AG4,""           "",'Testing Report'!AH4,'Testing Report'!AI4," & _
     "'Testing Report'!AJ4," & Format(lastrow - 2, "00") & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time out to respond! I implemented your code and it does not seem to be affecting the output. Any suggestions on what could be hampering the change?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this earlier, but the file is a .csv. Maybe that is impacting the leading zeros?

Comment: I think you need to give us a couple of example records with and without the leading zero

Comment: Sure - So If I use Format as suggested the output comes out like this....0000000X - Where the 7 zeros are a static field exported from the 3rd party platform and X is the record count per the formula in the original question.

Comment: That's the complete output of the CONCATENATE()?  What about *without* the Format() ?

Comment: Without the format the output is the exact same actually. I think the issue is that because the cell format is general the formula is padding the zero and then excel is removing it. I came to this conclusion because I changed the "00" to "9" and it replaced the X with 9 in the record count output whereas "00" would not output any changes to the record count. Is it possible to embed a line of code in the formula to change the cell from General to Text?

Comment: The zero-padded value is going at the end of the output, so it shouldn't affect how Excel renders the value...

Comment: Interesting - Does anything else come to mind as to why Format is not adding anything to the end when I use "00" but does when I use "99" or anything other than zero?

Comment: I can't say.  If you can share a sample worksheet that your code uses I can take a look. Anonymize/redact as needed.

Comment: Sure - would love to. What would be the best way for me to send over/share my document?

Comment: Perfect - Thanks! Will send over soon.